# Linux | Shell implementation in C | Input redirection does not display

Tags: c, linux, shell, io-redirection

I'm implementing shell in C and when implementing the redirection operation, I see that the output redirection works fine but the input redirection operation doesn't do anything. (no display is given in the stdout)

```
COMMAND-> wc < out.txt
Child 12878 died 0x008B

COMMAND->
```

[where COMMAND-> is my prompt]

When I print the status of the child when it dies, it gets a value of 0x8B. Does this signify anything?

I've followed this post and the core part of the implementation of redirection is similar to what is suggested here.
[Implementing shell in C and need help handling input/output redirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515399/implementing-shell-in-c-and-need-help-handling-input-output-redirection)

This is the gist of what is happening at the input redirection :

```
in = open(file_name, O_RDONLY);
dup2(in,0);
close(in);
execvp("wc",args);
```

(I cannot post my entire code since this is a live homework and I might end up caught with MOSS)

Comment: Exit code 0x008b (139: Segmentatation violation) usually means it was terminated by a `SIGSEGV`, you have a segmentation fault somewhere, `gdb` should be able to tell you more.

Comment: gdb doesn't detect it as segmentation fault. Behaves the same.

Comment: I would add that since `wc` itself is unlikely to segfault even if you gave it invalid file descriptor, the segfault is probably between the `fork` call and the `exec` of the actual command and in there most probably in the code setting up the redirection (as you say it only fails with redirection).

Comment: You have to set up tracing into the child process in `gdb`. Using `set follow-fork-mode child`. It will trace the first child, so you have to only set it just before running the command.

Comment: What process had PID "12878"? If you are using `exec*` functions on each process how are you handling "out.txt" as your process? Are you passing it as an argument to a `cat` process?

Comment: @JanHudec When I used the command in gdb I got segmentation fault. When I did bt, I got this call from my main #0  0x0000003f4bcab552 in execvpe () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: What's the output of `where`? What arguments were passed to `execvpe`?

Comment: @soulseekah wc took the PID 12878. I use execvp with wc as argument. The input redirection filename is opened via open command and stdin is replaced with this using dup2 command.

Comment: I've added my core code guys.

Comment: `gdb` should be pretty clear in where the segmentation fault occurs and what brought it about. Paste the backtrace, please. Those new 4 lines of code appear to be fine, apart from perhaps a missing `exit` or `return` next to `execvp` to avoid it falling through on error and causing chaos if not prepared for this.

Comment: The segmentation fault started from execvp. And the exit is present in my code.

Comment: Where's the backtrace? It's really hard to "imagine" it all correctly based off what you provided; need more information to avoid guessing. What is `args`? Many questions, again the code above seems fine. An `strace -f` would also be very insightful, @Vinoth.

Comment: I'm out now and I'm replying from mobile. Sorry. Will pull those details ASAP. Could you brief on starc?

Comment: This is what I get in the gdb segmentation fault sequence `#0  0x0000003f4bcab552 in execvpe () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000000000401620 in main () at src/shell.c:145`

Comment: You still need to provide the `strace -f` and the contents of `args`; maybe `args` is the perpetrator?

Answer (score 0):

The pointer which was passed in the `execvp` was `NULL` and hence got `SIGSEGV`.

The backend processing of the entered command to segregate them based on pipes and redirection had error.