# C pipe redirection issue

Tags: c, shell, unix

So I've looked around here at some answers that are related to my question and have used a bit of the code (mainly from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11518304/1852119) however, I can't seem to figure out how to get my program to work as expected.

**Expected output**:

$> ls > ls.txt | cat

ls.txt should be populated with the output of "ls", and the shell should display the output of cat (with cat's input being ls)

**Actual output:**

$> ls > ls.txt | cat

It displays the output of cat (with input of cat being "ls") correctly, however when I check the ls.txt file, it does not exist (was never created).

**Here's my code:**

```
int redirect(int redirect_type, int prev_stdin, char ** argv, char * filename) {
int returnfd;
int status;
fflush(0);
pid = fork();
if(pid < 0) err_sys("Error creating child process.");
if(pid == 0) {
  if(redirect_type == REDIRECT_STDOUT) {
    int fd0 = creat(filename, 0644);
    dup2(prev_stdin, STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fd0, STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd0);
  } else {
    int fd1 = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
    dup2(fd1, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd1);
  }

  if(execvp(argv[0], argv) == -1) err_sys("Error executing command ");
}
returnfd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
return returnfd;
}
```

prev_stdin is the output of the previous command run, and it works by creating the file, putting the file's fd as the stdout_fileno, running the command and closing the file. It then creates a new file descriptor that opens the file that was just created and returns it as the prev_stdin for the next command.

The next command recieves the correct input, which means that the file had to of been created (so it can be opened again as the return value), so it makes me think that it's a file closing issue, however I closed the file already in the child process and running just a single command (such as $ ls > ls.txt) works perfectly as expected.

I'm stumped, please help!

Thanks,

Alex.

Comment: Hmm. Is the output of your commands missing?

Comment: Martin, I'm not sure what you mean. The output of the commands is redirected into fd0 at the line "dup2(fd0, STDOUT_FILENO)"

Comment: You can either pipe the output to another program with "|" or you can redirect it to a file with ">" but not both.  For that, use "tee".

Comment: Stark, how com running the command in zsh produces the expected result? Does  zsh just run tee when it detects a "? > ? | ?"-type command?

Comment: Yes, zsh allows multiple redirections that work like tee: `foo >bar >baz`. sh, bash, ksh... don't do that.

Comment: Ah okay. So I've been messing around with different ideas & searching the internet for answers for a few hours because of a misunderstanding then. Thanks for the help stark & n.m.!

Comment: zsh multiple redirection basically implements `tee` (strace will confirm that). You can't do it using traditional open/dup2 like you can with single redirection.