# My custom shell program redirects only one line

Tags: c, shell

We are trying to make a simple shell. In this shell currently every built-in linux commands works properly. For example `ls` prints:

```
bbb.txt  cccc.txt  cmake-build-debug  CMakeLists.txt  e444.txt  library.c  library.h  mainSetup  mainSetup.c  nnnn.txt  qwe.txt  wqeqwe.txt  yyyy.txt
```

When i try to redirect this output to a file it only writes currently created file. For example i write `ls > myfile.txt` content of the myfile.txt will be `myfile.txt`. I don't know why it prints only its line and ignore other lines. Here is my redirection code:

```
    int fd = open(findTheLastArg(args, 0), O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_APPEND, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
                    dup2(fd, 1);   // make stdout go to file
                    close(fd);
 splitter(args);
```

`findTheLastArg(args, 0)` returns the file name in the command line.

`splitter(args)` containts execl function and works properly when i'm not trying to redirect anything.

Edit: my **set** **NULL** method is:

```
void setFileAndArrowNull(char *args[], int counter){

    for(int i=0; i < counter; i++){

        if (strcmp(args[i], ">") == 0) {
            args[i] = NULL;
            args[i+1] = NULL;
            args[i+2] = NULL;
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

I'm calling this method in here:

```
  if(redirect){
                    setFileAndArrowNull(argv, 0);
                }
exec(....);
```

**Redirect** becomes 1 when line contains '>'. The program enters in this if.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] (and fix your indentation).

Comment: I am not sure how relevant _[this post is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11515399/implementing-shell-in-c-and-need-help-handling-input-output-redirection)_ but it may help...

Comment: @ryyker thanks i tried before but it gives same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description and glimpses of the code, I'm guessing you don't remove `>` and `myfile.txt` from the arguments array.

If you enter:

```
ls > myfile.txt
```

then the argument array you execute the program with must be:

```
{"ls", NULL}
```

It CANNOT be:

```
{"ls", ">", "myfile.txt", NULL}
```

because in the that case, it'll just show an error and the output file will just contain itself, just like you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried what you tell me. I tried to set arrow null yesterday but never thought to make the other parts null. So today i've tried to set them null too.  But i still get the same result. I added my setNull method and where i used them. Could you help me?

Comment: What's the contents of the file if you run `echo hello > myfile.txt` ?

Comment: `hello myfile.txt`

Comment: Sounds like `>` is removed while `myfile.txt` is not. You can check this with a debugger or `strace -f`

Comment: i just noticed that my program never enters if statement in set Null method. I have exactly same method for checking '&' for background processes and works properly.

Comment: I finally did it. In somewhere make `'\0'` argument arrray make this problem occur. So array be trimmed so much earlier before execution and some arguments can't make it to `exec` function. Thank you so much.